# Inconsistent behavior in C# 8 nullable reference type handling with generics

Tags: c#, generics, nullable-reference-types

I have this code:

```
public T? Foo<T>()
    where T : class?
{
    return null;
}
```

It gives an error that is logical and expected:

> A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

Now I add one more constraint:

```
public T? Foo<T>()
    where T : class?, IDisposable // Could be any interface I guess
{
    return null;
}
```

Now interestingly enough error has just disappeared. Though it really seems to me we have conflicting constraints since interface is `non-nullalbe` while `class?` is.

Am I missing something here or is there a trouble with compiler?

Comment: You need `IDisposable?`. Yes it's confusing.

Comment: Have you seen this? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975211/nullable-reference-types-how-to-specify-t-type-without-constraining-to-class

Comment: Yeah, I tested with with `?`, and it compiles. Ironically enough it also compiles like that `where T : class, IDisposable?`

Comment: It seems the whole constraint is non-nullable if at least one constraint is non-nullable

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik sounds conclusive, since the constraints are AND-connected.

Comment: Are you sure it disappeared? I am still getting it.

Comment: Yes, for example, if you are making the constraints that T is both int and int? then T must always be non-null because that is the only way that it conforms to both requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The generic type constraint `where T : IDisposable` means "`T` must be non-nullable and must implement `IDisposable`". Where you have multiple generic type constraints of differing nullabilities, the constraint overall is only nullable if all constraints are nullable.

So the fact that `class?` is nullable gets overridden by the fact that `IDisposable` is not.

You need `where T : class?, IDisposable?`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems it works this way, but it's kind of not obvious really and somewhat confusing. I have additionally tried to return nullable whith such a constraint, but that does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631460/c-sharp-8-gives-a-warning-when-returning-a-nullable-generic-with-nullable-constr

Comment: Agreed, I find it non-obvious and confusing as well. And easily forgotten!