# generic class using nullable property of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, nullable-reference-types

I have the following class:

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T? A { get; init; }
    public T B { get; init; }

    public GenericClass(T? a, T b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

I want to use it for any sort of `T`, no matter if `struct`, `class`, `enum`. I merely want to make sure that property `A` can always be null while property `B`'s nullable-ness is the same as `T`'s. But this does not seem to work.

If I write

```
static void MyTestMethod()
{
    var vStruct = new GenericClass<bool>(null, true);
    var vNullableStruct = new GenericClass<bool?>(null, true);
    var vClass = new GenericClass<string>(null, "hello");
    var vNullableClass = new GenericClass<string?>(null, "hello");
    var vEnum = new GenericClass<Color>(null, Color.red);
    var vNullableEnum = new GenericClass<Color?>(null, Color.red);
}
```

where `Color` is defined as `enum Color { red, green, blue }`,

I get compiler error CS1503 for `vStruct` and `vEnum`:

> Argument '1': cannot convert from `<NULL>` to `bool`/`Color`

In both cases, the mouseover for `new GenericClass<...>` shows both arguments as non-nullable although I clearly defined `A` as nullable. **Why?**

I can add a type constraint: `class GenericClass<T> where T : struct`, which will leave the two previously erroneous lines (`vStruct` and `vEnum`) error-free, but will mark all others as erroneous. This time with compiler error CS0453:

> The type `bool?`/`string`/`string?`/`Color` must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter `T` in the generic type or method `GenericClass<T>`.

Which makes perfectly sense; they are not `struct`.

**But how do I make my `GenericClass<T>` work for both classes and structs/enums?**

Comment: Despite superficial similarities, nullable-ness is implemented *entirely differently* for structs and classes.. The compiler *cannot* emit a definition of the generic class that will work for both.

Comment: I think it's coming in C#11

Comment: This is a weakness of the nullable system in c#. It is one reason a custom Option/Maybe type may still be useful.

Comment: @JonasH If the official `Option` type isn't a monad we're going to have another holy-war [like JavaScript's `Promise`](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94)

Comment: @McNets I think that's the `never-`default`" constraint you're referring to

Answer (score 4):

The comment by sjb-sjb below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796924/5333340) provides the answer to my "why":

> As it is, in C#9, with T unconstrained (or even constrained to notnull), the syntax "T?" means "the defaultable type corresponding to T" instead of "the nullable type corresponding to T" as it does everywhere else in the language. However if you constrain T to class or struct then "T?" starts meaning "the nullable type corresponding to T" again.

Thanks to JonasH's comment I came up with a solution/workaround. I created a custom `Nullable<T>` type with an implicit conversion from `T?` to `Nullable<T>` so that I can use *almost* the same syntax in construction of `GenericClass<...>` as I used in my question:

```
struct Nullable<T>
{
    public static Nullable<T> Null => new Nullable<T>(false, default(T)!);
    public bool HasValue { get; init; }

    private T? _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get => HasValue ? _value
            : throw new System.InvalidOperationException("no value present!");
        init => _value = value;
    }

    private Nullable(bool hasValue, T value)
    {
        HasValue = hasValue;
        _value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T? n)
        => n == null ? Null : new Nullable<T>(true, n);

}
```

The two problematic lines

```
var vStruct = new GenericClass<bool>(null, true);
var vEnum = new GenericClass<Color>(null, Color.red);
```

still throw CS1503, but I can change them to

```
var vStruct = new GenericClass<bool>(Nullable<bool>.Null, true);
var vEnum = new GenericClass<Color>(Nullable<Color>.Null, Color.red);
```

and it works. I could do the same for the other lines, but I do not need to; the implicit conversion is used there.

Comment: `public static Nullable<T> NULL => new Nullable<T>(false, default(T)!);` can be just `public static Nullable<T> Null => default;` btw. (Also, don't use ALL_CAPS names for public types and members in C# or .NET)

Comment: A tip, create a non generic `Nullable`-type without any fields and a static `Nullable Null = new ()` property, with a implicit conversion operator from this type to your `Nullable<T>`, allowing you to write `new GenericClass<bool>(Nullable.Null, true)`.

Comment: @JonasH or even easier: create an `enum Nullable { Null }`. Then add the implicit conversion `public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(Nullable n) => Null;` to `Nullable<T>`.