# Problem matching return type for IEnumerable and nullable

Tags: c#, interface

I am very new to C# and I have the following interfaces, ICrud

```
{
    public interface ICrud <T>
    {
        int Add(T Entity);
        void Delete(T Entity);
        void Update(int ID,T Entity);
        T GetByID(int ID);
        IEnumerable<T?> GetTheList();
    }
}
```

and an other one called IOrder which inherits from the previous one (ICrud)

```
using DO;
namespace DalApi
{
    public interface IOrder : ICrud<Order>
    {
     
    }
}
```

And this class that implements the IOrder interface, therefore the ICrud too, and I keep having the problem that when I put the nullable operator (?) in the last lines

```
public IEnumerable<Order?> GetTheList()
    {
        return DataSource.LOrder;
    }
```

it tells me `'DalOrder' does not implement interface member 'ICrud<Order>.GetTheList()'. 'DalOrder.GetTheList()' cannot implement 'ICrud<Order>.GetTheList()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerable<Order>'.` and it disappears when I remove the operator from IEnumerable, but I need to keep it

```
using DalApi;
namespace Dal;
internal class DalOrder : IOrder
{

    public int Add(Order order)
        ///add order to orderlist
    {
        DataSource.LOrder.Add(order);
        DataSource.Config.I_Order++;
        return order.ID;


    }
    public void Update(int ID, Order order)
    {
        Order temporderitem =DataSource.searchOrder(ID)?? throw new MyException("the id is null");
        Delete(temporderitem);
        Add(order);

    }
    public void Delete(Order dorder)
    {
        DataSource.LOrder.Remove(DataSource.searchOrder(dorder.ID));
        DataSource.Config.I_Order--;
    }

    public int Order_Length()
    {
        return DataSource.Config.I_Order;
    }
    public Order GetByID(int ID)
    {
      Order order= DataSource.searchOrder(ID)??throw new MyException("the id is null");
        return order;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Order?> GetTheList()
    {
        return DataSource.LOrder;
    }
```

If someone has any ideas on how to solve this

Comment: Would you please attach the code of `Order` class?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? According to this answer to [Nullable reference types: How to specify "T?" type without constraining to class or struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796924/880990) is makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe Nullable<IEnumerable<T>>

Comment: @HamidMohammadi I can but its very big

Comment: Do you have nullable reference types enabled in all your files?

Comment: @LeS Is it class or struct? if you are using `struct` you have to add `where T : struct` in front of `ICrud<T>` interface. otherwise maybe the problem is depends on your C# version

Answer (score 2):

I think you have another issue going on here.

The following code works just fine for me with no errors or warnings.

```cs
public class Order
{
}

public interface ICrud<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T?> GetTheList();
}

public interface IOrder : ICrud<Order>
{
}

public class DalOrder : IOrder
{
    public IEnumerable<Order?> GetTheList()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Order>();
    }
}
```

One thing is that `?` can have two meanings. In some cases, it can mean it's a nullable value type. For example, `int?`.

But in other cases, it can be used on reference types to let the compiler know that this variable might be null. For example, `string?`.

If you mix these two types, you might see an error like this.

Do you have nullable reference types enabled on all your files? Try adding `#nullable enabled` at the very top of each file if you aren't sure.

It might be helpful to know what version of C# you're using. And we need to know if `Order` is a class or what.

*Note: A better approach is to have this method return `IEnumerable<Order>` and not `IEnumerable<Order?>`. It's hard to think of many cases where you are interested in the entries that are null. And, if for some reason you have them, you could filter them using `DataSource.LOrder.Where(o => o != null)`*